# Firefox's about:config on Android for setting pdf application

Tags: pdf, firefox

https://www.ghacks.net/2020/01/06/aboutconfig-is-blocked-in-firefox-preview-stable-and-beta/

writes that about:config is inhibited in new Android Firefoxes and indeed I experience this.

How can I then set the default pdf reading application?